# Http Post from AngularJS is reading empty, am I doing something wrong?

Tags: python, angularjs, django, django-request

So I have been going at this for hours. Usually this works out for me so I decided to ask for some help. My Http Post from AngularJS:

```
$scope.receipt_pay_update = function(){

        response = confirm("Do you want to continue with the changes?")

        if(!response){
            return;
        }
        var data = {

            'items': "ABC",

        }

        console.log($scope.current_farmer)
        $http.post('/foodhub/dashboard/receipt_pay_modal_update',data, {data: JSON}
        )}
```

Here is my views.py for the request:

```
def receipt_pay_modal_update(request):
    import sys
    reload(sys)
    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')



    print "#$$$$##$$$#$$$$##$$$#$$$$##$$$#$$$$##$$$#$$$$##$$$#$$$$##$$$#$$$$##$$$#$$$$##$$$#$$$$##$$$"
    print request
    print "#$$$$##$$$#$$$$##$$$#$$$$##$$$#$$$$##$$$#$$$$##$$$#$$$$##$$$#$$$$##$$$#$$$$##$$$#$$$$##$$$"
    print request.GET
```

I am trying to get that "ABC" but it keeps showing empty. Here is my logs:

```
#$$$$##$$$#$$$$##$$$#$$$$##$$$#$$$$##$$$#$$$$##$$$#$$$$##$$$#$$$$##$$$#$$$$##$$$#$$$$##$$$
<WSGIRequest: GET '/foodhub/dashboard/receipt_pay_modal_update/'>
#$$$$##$$$#$$$$##$$$#$$$$##$$$#$$$$##$$$#$$$$##$$$#$$$$##$$$#$$$$##$$$#$$$$##$$$#$$$$##$$$
<QueryDict: {}>
```

This usually works for me so I have no idea what is happening.

EDIT: So even though I am doing a `POST` I keep getting `GET` in the request body

Comment: You are doing a POST. There will be nothing in `request.GET` then, try `request.POST`.

Comment: Hmm I'm still getting `<QueryDict: {}>`

Comment: where are you returning response?

Comment: I don't believe I have a return for response.